# How much can i improve for a marathon in 2 months?

Tags: running-training-plan

I can run a 10K in 50 minutes if I try hard but I typically run it in one hour. I used to run a 10K each morning. I haven't tried to go farther than 10K.

I am planning to compete in a 10K after 2 months of training. Given my current time, I'm wondering how to improve speed.

I feel like I should run a 10k everyday for the next 60 - 65 days without any break, but then take 2 or 3 days break before the race. I do a little cycling also but I'm not sure if that helps. Also, should I try increasing my distance up to 20k or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general rule of running is to gradually increase your miles by no more than 10% per week. So a 10 mile week can turn into an 11 mile week. There are a lot of [marathon training calendars](http://www.yourtrainingcalendar.com/) you can find online that will give you the day-by-day schedule. Often these require shorter (and faster) days on Monday and Wednesday, with a longer and slower run (aimed for distance) on Saturday.

One thing I'd really ask yourself is: **What Are Your Expectations For Your Marathon?**

Are you trying to:

- Simply complete it?
- Complete it without stopping?
- Put in a < 4 Hour time?
- Qualify for some higher level event (Boston Martahon, etc)?

These create very different training requirements. I know several people who've simply shown up, rather out of shape, and "finished" a marathon. The closer you get to wanting to put in an aggressive time, the harder you will train. And honestly, *training to be competitive at marathon running is very time intensive.* Your life will revolve around your training for months.